# ActiveAdmin Single Table Inheritance common attributes form rewrite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin, single-table-inheritance

I'm using ActiveAdmin and I have a project with Single Table Inheritance. My question is simple: is possible to write only once the form of the common parts of my models or i am forced to rewrite it every time?

Answer (score 4):

You can use ruby's `#to_proc` and trick with conversion of a proc into a block.

Here's my solution leveraging it. It allows for normal code reloading, doesn't extend/monkey patch any existing modules and allows for customization of admin definitions.

In this example `Animal` is base STI class, `Dog` and `Cat` are inheriting from it.

Put the following code into `app/admin/animal.rb`:

```
class AnimalAdminConfig
  attr_reader :opts

  def initialize(opts = {})
    @opts = opts
  end

  def to_proc
    this = self

    proc do
      scope :active

      index do
        column this.opts[:name_label], :name
        column ....
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Put the following code into `app/admin/cat.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register(Cat, &AnimalAdminConfig.new(name_label: "Kitten's name"))
```

Put the following code into `app/admin/dog.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register(Dog, &AnimalAdminConfig.new(name_label: "Puppy's name"))
```

Comment: How would you add some customization to a particular subclass? Can we maybe pass block to `AnimalAdminCofig`'s constructor?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as you, and here is the solution that I came up with:

I had about 4 models that all inherit from `Venue` and I was re-writing all the params and logic for each one.

in `config/initializers/active_admin_shared_venue_resources.rb`

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class DSL

    def shared_venue_methods_and_traits(options={})

      #all your shared logic here

    end
  end
end
```

and then in `admin/your_model.rb` you just need to include whatever you called your method:

```
ActiveAdmin.register InheritedModel do
  menu priority: 1

  shared_venue_methods_and_traits
end
```

That will inject all the code from your initializer into the model.

**THE CATCH:** You will have to restart your server whenever you change the config file

#### Update:

For the forms I did the following:

Create a partial that has all the fields in `views/admin/shared/_shared_form.html.erb`

and then in `views/admin/inherited_models/_your_form.html.erb` you can put the following:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @inherited_model], html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <%= render '/admin/shared/shared_form', f: f, venue: @inherited_model %>
<% end %>
```

The `venue` variable isn't required. But will give you a way to call the `@inherited_model` variable in your form if you need to